# How can I get all the source dependencies SCons computed for a given target?

Tags: scons, build-dependencies, incremental-build

I want to do this programmatically right after a given target is built, during SCons build run, not with `--tree` or any other command to scons. I have a target node. It might have had some explicit dependencies, used scanners, file extension-based scanners, and whatever else SCons calculated. So like:

```
all_source_nodes = tgt_node.get_all_sources(...)
```

I searched the docs and the APIs. Only saw `get_stored_implicit` on FS nodes. I get None on that and also for `.prerequisites` and `.implicit` Node members.

I also found that `.sources` Node member shows direct sources that were passed into the builder. That's not enough too, of course, because I need essentially all the nodes of the dependency sub-tree, which is a lot more.

Comment: What will you do with this information?  This will help find a possible solution.

Comment: We have a tool that captures all the files read and written during the build process for any given target. I need to add verification that all the files read were declared as dependencies. My plan is to add a step at the end of the build that checks the declared dependencies against the actual. This will make incremental build more reliable.

Comment: Actually, I just found there's this: 
`all_children(self, scan=1)
# Return a list of all the node's direct children.
`
It gets almost everything (some scanned dependencies are still missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! :) A combination of build info data and recursive scanner application got me everything `scons --tree=prune` reports. Full code below, along with some informational messages.

```
__FULL_DEPS = {}    # all dependencies for the node and its children recursively
__DIRECT_DEPS = {}  # only the dependencies obtained from SCons for the node itself (direct and scanned)

# Find scons deps for this target - these are all in the subtree (same as __FULL_DEPS[tgt])
scons_deps = find_deps(tgt, None, env)
tgt_deps = set(map(str, scons_deps))    # Some nodes refer to the same paths

def find_deps(node, children_func, env):
    """Recursively traverses children dependencies from build info and by applying 
children_func (scanner) to collect the full set of all dependencies 
starting with 'node' as the dependency tree root.
:Parameters:
    - node          the current target we check (root node of the sub-tree)
    - children_func the function called to get the children of a node. May be None.
    - env           the current environment
:Return:
    The set of all source nodes in the dependency sub-tree
    While the node objects are unique, the underlying files/dirs may repeat on rare occasions.
    Collects the global __DIRECT_DEPS and __FULL_DEPS caches
    """
    if node in __FULL_DEPS:
        print("_find_deps '{}' deps - from CACHE: {}."
                            .format(str(node), len(__FULL_DEPS[node])))
        return __FULL_DEPS[node]
    children = set(node.all_children())  # children may repeat
    
    # Apply children func, if available and merge in the results
    scanned_deps = set()
    if children_func:
        scanned_deps = set(children_func(node))
        children |= scanned_deps
    __DIRECT_DEPS[node] = children

    # Iterate all the unvisited children and recursively call find_deps with children_func 
    # specific to each child.
    # FYI: Scanner use code is based on SCons code in Node.render_include_tree()
    subtree_deps = set()
    for child in sorted(children):
        scanner = node.get_source_scanner(child)
        # Note: get_build_scanner_path fails on nodes without executor
        scanner_path = node.get_build_scanner_path(scanner) if (scanner and node.get_executor()) else None
        def children_func(node, env=env, scanner=scanner, path=None):
            return node.get_found_includes(env, scanner, path)
    
        subtree_deps |= find_deps(child, children_func, env)
        __FULL_DEPS[node] = children | subtree_deps

    print("_find_deps '{}' deps: {} children ({} scanned) + {} from sub-tree"
        .format(str(node), len(children), len(scanned_deps), len(subtree_deps)))

return __FULL_DEPS[node]
```

Getting 700+ dependencies in about a second on a high performance machine. This should be called in a post-action, i.e. after the node is built. Probably will still work fine when called just before the node is built.

Comment: Wow! Why didn't I notice `all_children(self, scan=1)` method on Node before!? It eliminates the need of using `build_info` ( `node.get_binfo()` ). What's even better is that it works with -n option too, while `build_info` won't have `bsources`, `bdepends`, etc. for some types of nodes in that situation.
I was hoping I can also rid of all the children_func scanner business, because `all_children()` is supposed to scan, but it turns out it somehow still misses some scanned dependencies, so I have to keep that.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get most of that information at the time the SConstruct/SConscript is processed.

The dependency graph is fully populated after that.

Likely you can use [sconsign](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/sconsign-man.html) for that.
It reads the build database after SCons has completed and you can query for a specific target.

Comment: When should I do it, then? I suppose I can run something to do what `--tree` does internally. Or can I hook something to run before the building of targets starts?

Comment: Good tip, though, @bdbaddog! I already have a SCons.Build wrapper for the targets we care about. I can collect SCons dependency info for the target before the command runs, by something similar to `SCons.Node.render_tree()`, and then compare to the captured I/O in a post-run step I already have (for reports).

Comment: You'd likely do this in an function called by AtExit()?  That way you can be sure it's run after the build. Also this information is present in the .sconsign file..

Comment: No, I will need this per target, so doing it post-build for a given target within the Builder wrapper seems the best. I am experimenting, but so far I can't get all the children. I recursively iterate through .children and whatever scanner returns, but I only get a small fraction compared to what can be obtained with `--tree`. Not sure what's missing.
I am surprised SCons doesn't have a ready function that returns all the dependents.

Comment: You won't get that information while SConstructs are being processed. It's not there yet. The DAG is built and fleshed out after the SConstructs are processed.  So you'd likely be able to get the information via a AddPostAction.

Comment: Understood. Builder wrapper I am talking about wraps execution of the build process/command for each target. So that would be equivalent to the post-action. The trouble is that I am not getting all the source dependencies for a node. Hence my original question stands.

Comment: get_all_sources() returns only the specified sources.  Did you try to access the implicit sources in a post action?

Comment: can you provide (in the initial question, which is editable), an small example and show which files you are not finding which you would expect?

Comment: also expand on what you mean by "Builder wrapper"?

Comment: Builder wrapper: instead of Builder, I call MyBuilder which wraps actions, so my code gets called to provide some common behavior. MyBuilder passes the modified **kw parameters to Builder
    The "action" or "generator" key must exist in order for a target to be built. We process the kw dictionary then pass it to SCons.Builder.
    kw["generator"] must be a function that returns a string. Instead of passing the generator to SCons Builder, we pass it to the action wrapper which generates the command string at runtime and passes it to our run_command().